# How do I validate that a string value is in the format "\/Date(1239018869048)\/"?

Tags: javascript, regex, json, validation, date

How do I validate that a string/JSON value is in the format `"\/Date(1239018869048)\/"`?

I'm iterating through a JSON object, I know I may have a serialized JSON date string but because the JSON object is dynamic, I don't know which property is the serialized JSON date.

So I want to know if a JSON property value will validate to the format of a JSON serialized date.

**Update #1**

It would be nice to check if it's an instance of a string before you use the regular expression because an integer will throw an exception. This is in addition to the answer @vzwick gave. Thanks once again.

```
json_obj = { 'foo' : 'bar', 'baz' : '/Date(1239018869048)/' }

pattern = /^\/Date\((\d*)\)\/$/;
for(e in json_obj) {
    if (json_obj[e].constructor === String) {
      if (json_obj[e].match(pattern)) {
        // date found
      }
    }
}
```

**Update #2**

After tryout different values, i discovered that we have negative numbers. So the pattern can 
now look like;

```
pattern = /^\/Date\((-?\d*)\)\/$/;
```

Comment: Do you mean that string literally?  Do you mean that literal string as a regexp?  Or do you mean a literal 'Date' open parenthesis, string of digits x characters long, close parenthesis?

Comment: I want to know if a string value is in this format:  /Date(1239018869048)/.

Comment: If by "in this format" you mean "matches this regexp" you can just do a comparison against that since it has no dynamic patterns in it.  If that's not what you mean, then I'm afraid I'm confused. For regexp matching: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match or just pattern.test("some string") example: /^[0-9]+$/.test("12345")

Comment: I would love the regular expression that matches that format. Note: The figures within the brackets are dynamic and can only by numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, mate:

```
json_obj = { 'foo' : 'bar', 'baz' : '/Date(1239018869048)/' }

pattern = /^\/Date\((\d*)\)\/$/;
for(e in json_obj) {
    if (json_obj[e].match(pattern)) {
        // date found
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning to the OP: If you want it to match exactly, you can use: /^\/Date\((\d*)\)\/$/  That will only match strings that contain only that valid format.  Without the ^ and $, it will match any string that contains that format anywhere in it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. And thanks to @Corbin too for the insight and addition.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean validate that a string value will serialise into a date, you can use JavaScripts support for regular expressions.

See here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

If you mean validate that a de-serialised value is a date, you can use Javascripts instanceof operator.

See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/instanceof

Comment: I know the existence of regular expressions. I would love the regular expression.

Comment: You can do some basic testing of Javascript regular expressions here http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html